# How do I SELECT for the following?

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I have a table with two columns of ids.

```
TABLE
id1     id2
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       1
2       6
2       2
3       1
3       10
3       3
```

I would like to SELECT every id1 that is matched to a certain combination of id2s.

For example, if I have id2 = [1, 2, 3] I would like to return id1 = [1];

If I have id2 = [1, 6] I would like to return id1 = [2];

If I have id2 = [1] I would like to return id1 = [1, 2, 3].

Any suggestions on how to best accomplish this would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Why id[1,6] return only [2] ?

Comment: @Patrick only for id1=2 the corresponding id2 contains both 1 and 6.

Comment: @Patrick - because 2 is the only value for id1 that has id2 values 1 AND 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for matching id2's, and use `count(distinct id2)` to verify that all id2's were matched.  The count should be equal to the number of id2's. For id2 = [1,2,3], the count should be 3:

```
select id1 
from YourTable
where id2 in (1,2,3)
group by id1
having count(distinct id2) = 3;
```

This prints 1.  For id2 = [1,6]:

```
select id1 
from YourTable
where id2 in (1,6)
group by id1
having count(distinct id2) = 2;
```

This prints 2.  For id2 = [1]:

```
select id1 
from YourTable
where id2 in (1)
group by id1
having count(distinct id2) = 1;
```

This prints 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id1
AS found_id1
FROM table
WHERE id2 IN (1, 2, 3)
```

You will get:

```
DISTINCT id1
--------
1
```